Mixing hand sanitizer with Clorox surface wipe
during cleaning my phone I mixed Clorox surface wipes ( no bleach) with hand sanitizer (ethyl alcohol with some inactive ingredient).
I’m attaching both products ingredients.


Would there be any toxic chemical reaction between these two product?

There might be -- look reaction of ethanol and hypochlorites. However, health questions are off topic.

Which ingredient are you referring to as hypochlorite in this ingredients list?

Clorox is known for having that ingredient in some products, but not these.

I do not spot any problematic reaction. Both products are basically the same: ethanol or isopropanol with some fragrance and some larger molecules to make the active small alcohol evaporate more slowly.

Thanks, much appreciated. Is the dimethyl benzoyl ammonium chloride the main ingredient for this product?
